# Grunt VSO VM MSBuild

Tags: gruntjs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I've been trying install grunt on the vm for vso task, but for some reason i get an error "null --gruntfile"

Does any body know from live experience how to install grunt properly?

[image: grunt task]

task setup works fine with hosted but not with my vm.
Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I get it work via following steps:

1. Install Node v4.2.2 TLS from https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Run command from CMD: `npm install -g bower`
3. Run command from CMD: `npm install -g -grunt-cli`